# Terraform hangs with no output

Tags: terraform

I am running terraform v0.9.6 version on Windows 7. When I run any terraform command I get stuck at the following:

```
D:\terraforma>terraform destroy
Do you really want to destroy?
  Terraform will delete all your managed infrastructure.
  There is no undo. Only 'yes' will be accepted to confirm.

  Enter a value: yes
```

There is no output after this for hours. Any pointer as to what could be the issue here? On enabling logging to level debug I get

```
------------------------
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: POST / HTTP/1.1
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: Host: sts.amazonaws.com
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.8.25
 (go1.8; windows; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.9.6
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: Content-Length: 43
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA2
56 Credential=AKIAJ2TUUX4QXSQBD6EA/20170601/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHe
aders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=dfd1cf69c9c110726ef
be5cfe6aeff5c16437f599e33a5ce5943dd9e04035bb2
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: Content-Type: application/x-w
ww-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: X-Amz-Date: 20170601T061356Z
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe:
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: Action=GetCallerIdentity&Vers
ion=2011-06-15
2017/06/01 11:43:56 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform.exe: -----------------------------
------------------------
2017/06/01 11:43:59 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "data.aws_ami.ubuntu", waiting for:
 "provider.aws"
2017/06/01 11:43:59 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "provider.aws (close)", waiting for
: "data.aws_ami.ubuntu"
2017/06/01 11:43:59 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "provider.aws
(close)"
2017/06/01 11:44:04 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "data.aws_ami.ubuntu", waiting for:
 "provider.aws"
2017/06/01 11:44:04 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "provider.aws (close)", waiting for
: "data.aws_ami.ubuntu"
2017/06/01 11:44:04 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "provider.aws
(close)"
2017/06/01 11:44:09 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "provider.aws (close)", waiting for
: "data.aws_ami.ubuntu"
2017/06/01 11:44:09 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "data.aws_ami.ubuntu", waiting for:
 "provider.aws"
2017/06/01 11:44:09 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "provider.aws
(close)"
2017/06/01 11:44:14 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "provider.aws (close)", waiting for
: "data.aws_ami.ubuntu"
2017/06/01 11:44:14 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "data.aws_ami.ubuntu", waiting for:
 "provider.aws"
2017/06/01 11:44:14 [DEBUG] dag/walk: vertex "root", waiting for: "provider.aws
(close)"
```

Comment: Did you run `terraform init` first?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with older versions of terraform where it hangs and loops forever if the AWS provider does some background checks and tries to connect to the metadata ip 169.254.169.254:80 [source code reference](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/9987f36d860b09877fe016986620471646bff851/builtin/providers/aws/provider.go#L44) before it moves on with further steps

To fix, you can add a rule to drop connection to `169.254.0.0/16` and it should work

it also advisable you upgrade to the latest stable version 0.9.8 (released: June 7, 2017)

See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/4043#issuecomment-161608689

Version releases Changelog: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from version `0.9.6` to version `0.10.6` fixed this exact problem for me.